# Get store base currency shopify

Tags: shopify

I am building an app for Shopify. My store has EUR as the base currency and supports different currencies such as USD, NZD,.. (I refer it as active currency).

I can get active currency with the javascript `window.Shopify.currency.active` and also the rate `window.Shopify.currency.rate`. How can I get the base currency symbol?

Comment: I am sure there is a Money or Currency package you can use where you input the string you get "USD" and get back a "$" All languages seem to have that, so pick yours.

Answer (score 4):

Shopify provides the [Currency object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/currency) depending on the theme page.

You can use `{{ cart.currency.symbol  }}` and `{{ checkout.currency.symbol  }}` in Cart page and Checkout page respectively.

For any other page, you can use the [Shop object](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/shop) to get the currency by using `{{ shop.currency }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `theme.moneyFormat`, it works for me:

```
var currentCurrent = theme.moneyFormat;
```

Whenever anyone changes currency, it will give current currency with symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`{{ currency.symbol }}`

[Shopify Reference](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/currency)

Comment: For me, currency doesn't appear to be a global object.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var currency;
        window.currency = '{{ cart.currency.symbol }}';
    });
</script>
```

Now your "currency" is a global variant. You can use it anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't get the base currency **symbol** as OP asked for.